# How can I get direct text without a tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an issue where I want to select (and replace) a string of text with no tags with jQuery. I need to retrieve the "us-east1-mp2 lobby", but it only selects the text with a span.

My code:

```js
function fixServerLocation() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if ($(".admin.chatLog").find(".section").length > 0) {
      var section = ($(".admin.chatLog").find(".section"));
      if (typeof section !== 'undefined') {
        var chatMessages = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='chatMessage']");
        if (typeof chatMessages !== 'undefined') {
          $('.section [id^="chatMessage"]').children('div.details').children().css({
            "color": "red",
            "border": "2px solid red"
          });;
          //The code that I currently have to select the tag-less text. The styling is only to highlight it.
        }
      }
    }
    fixServerLocation();
  }, 70);
}
fixServerLocation();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chatMessage listItem first" id="chatMessage-us-east1-mp2-6668675">
  <button class="expand small" type="button" tabindex="-1">+</button>
  <div class="options right"></div>
  <div class="details"><span class="time">2020-04-04 11:07</span>us-east1-mp2 lobby

    <span><span class="username adminLookup">CommanderAnime</span></span>:

    <span class="message ">Test</span></div>
</div>
```

How it currently looks when running the code:

[image]

I want to replace the "us-east1-mp2 lobby" with "Newark lobby". Thanks for any help

Comment: You can easily find what you need if you google before posting here, thanks

Comment: @Dexygen I haven't found anything for this exact instance which is why I'm asking.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit and add sections and chatlogs. They are not part of the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite dangerous if your text is part of text attributes

NOTE: because I remove the event handler when I rewrite the HTML, you will need to delegate the button:

`$("#someStaticContainerForTheChatMessages").on("click","button.expand",function() { whatever the button does })`

```js
$(function() {
  const $chatMessages = $("[id^='chatMessage']");
  if ($chatMessages.length > 0) {
    $chatMessages.each(function(i, message) {
      $('div.details', message).children().addClass("highlight")
      message.innerHTML = message.innerHTML.replace("us-east1-mp2 lobby", "Newark lobby")
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="chatMessage listItem first" id="chatMessage-us-east1-mp2-6668675">
  <button class="expand small" type="button" tabindex="-1">+</button>
  <div class="options right"></div>
  <div class="details"><span class="time">2020-04-04 11:07</span>us-east1-mp2 lobby<span><span class="username adminLookup">CommanderAnime</span></span>:

    <span class="message ">Test</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I'm having a bit of trouble with it, though. The code works just fine with replacing the lobby name, but it also renders the [+] button useless. Clicking it (or anything else, for that matter) doesn't do a thing.
Why is this, and how can it be fixed?

Again, thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: because I removed the event handler when I rewrote the HTML. You need to delegate the button: `$("#someStaticContainerForTheChatMessages").on("click","button.expand",function() { whatever the button does })`

Comment: I might have an issue with that. This code is for a chrome extension I'm working on, which styles and modifies a website. (beta.tanktrouble.com)
I don't have access to any of their code.
If possible, how can it be done without removing the event handler? Again, thanks

Comment: You can save it and add it again

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If using jquery, you can easily achieve this by using javascript `String.replace` method:

```
const detailsHtml = $('.details').html()
const replacedContent = detailsHtml.replace('us-east1-mp2 lobby', 'Newark lobby')

$('.details').html(replacedContent)
```

Whats the idea: As this text isn't inside a tag, you need to get the whole div html as a string, and perform a replace. The first line returns the html content of `.details` as a string.

Then we perform the replace and use the same `.html(value)` method to set the new content.

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/diogocosta/7wrmLog5/5/

```js
const detailsHtml = $('.details').html()
const replacedContent = detailsHtml.replace('us-east1-mp2 lobby', 'Newark lobby')
$('.details').html(replacedContent)

//console.log(replacedContent)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chatMessage listItem first" id="chatMessage-us-east1-mp2-6668675">
  <button class="expand small" type="button" tabindex="-1">+</button>
  <div class="options right"></div>
  <div class="details"><span class="time">2020-04-04 11:07</span>us-east1-mp2 lobby

    <span><span class="username adminLookup">CommanderAnime</span></span>:

    <span class="message ">Test</span></div>
</div>
```